# process is failing in ptrgl_64._ptrgl functionon aix

Tags: c, linux, unix, coredump

We are trying to port our code from HPX to AIX but getting core dump while running exe.

It's failing in some unknown function `ptrgl_64._ptrgl()`.

```
> ptrgl_64._ptrgl() at 0x900000084da0e48
> dfile_Proc(o_record =
> 0x0000000400000004, fileType =
> "^O\377\377\377\377\377TH^O\377\377\377\377\377TQ^O\377\377\377\377\377Ta^O\377\377\377\377\377T}",
> dist_dest = (nil), indicator = '\0',
> i_acCounters = (nil)), line 621 in
> "DISTfile.c" main(i_argc = 4, i_argv =
> 0x0fffffffffff34e8), line 66 in
> "main_EXEC.c"
```

Any idea about this issue?

Comment: This issue was due to invalid pointer value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called *pointer glue*, and is used to call functions through a pointer on PowerPC.  Because the pointer could point to a function in another module/shared object, the pointer glue is needed to set up the correct RTOC and environment pointer for that module and then jump to the function entry point.  If the function pointer was not valid then it will likely crash in the pointer glue, since that is where the pointer is actually dereferenced.

See section A.3.3 of the [PowerPC Compiler Writer's Guide](https://www-01.ibm.com/chips/techlib/techlib.nsf/techdocs/852569B20050FF7785256996007558C6) if you are interested in the full details.

Comment: Thanks mark it was the issue with the function pointer only.
+1 for explanation of pointer glue.

Answer (score 1):

> ptrgl_64._ptrgl() at 0x900000084da0e48
>   dfile_Proc(o_record = 0x0000000400000004,
>      fileType ="^O\377\377\377\377\377TH^O\377\377\377\377\377TQ^O\377\377\377\377\377Ta^O\377\377\377\377\377T}",
>      dist_dest = (nil), indicator = '\0', i_acCounters = (nil)), line 621 in "DISTfile.c"
>    main(i_argc = 4, i_argv = 0x0fffffffffff34e8), line 66 in "main_EXEC.c"

Look at line 621 of DISTfile.c.
    What is this line doing ?
    Is it calling a function through a function pointer ?
    What sort of problems might be caused by line 621 ?

Comment: yes we are calling function through function pointer array.
But what issue could be calused by function pointer?
same code is working perfectly fine on HPX?
I dont understand what is calling "ptrgl_64._ptrgl" function.
I cant find any thing on the google for this function.

Comment: thanks for your reply its was issue with function pointer only.