# AIX loadquery() return value interpretation (was also SEGV in 64-bit mode)

Tags: c, aix, dynamic-linking

I'm trying to compile Ruby 1.9.3-p125 on AIX 5.3 using xlc_r. I want to use the --enable-load-relative but that's dependent on the dladdr() function to get the pathname of the Ruby shared library and dladdr() isn't available on AIX. I found an implementation of dladdr() [here on root.cern.ch](http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/aix-and-dladdr) for AIX based on a call to loadquery(L_GETINFO).

The loadquery(L_GETINFO) call gets a list of the binary files that make up a program.  So to implement dladdr(), I'm doing a check to see if the address of the function passed to dladdr is between ldinfo_textorg and ldinfo_textorg+ldinfo_textsize. But the address of the function isn't within this address range for *any* of the structures returned.  Maybe I'm not correctly interpreting the ld_info structure.

I've attached the code I'm testing. Any help that can be rendered to these questions will be much appreciated.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ldr.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
  char* dli_fname;
} Dl_info;

int
dladdr(void* s, Dl_info* i) {
   size_t bufSize = 40960;
   struct ld_info* ldi;
   void *buf;
   int r;

   printf("sym at %lu\n", (ulong)s);
   buf = (void *)malloc(bufSize);
   if (!buf) {
     i->dli_fname = 0;
     return 0;
   }
   r = loadquery((int)L_GETINFO,  buf,  (int)bufSize);
   if (r == -1) {
     i->dli_fname = 0;
     return 0;
   }
   do {
     ldi = (struct ld_info*)buf;
     printf("checking %s, text %lu - %lu\n", ldi->ldinfo_filename, (ulong)ldi->ldinfo_textorg, (ulong)(ldi->ldinfo_textorg + ldi->ldinfo_textsize));
     if ((ldi->ldinfo_textorg <= s)
     &&  (s < (ldi->ldinfo_textorg + ldi->ldinfo_textsize))) {
       i->dli_fname = ldi->ldinfo_filename;
       return 1;
     }
     buf += ldi->ldinfo_next;
   } while (ldi->ldinfo_next);
   i->dli_fname = 0;
   return 0;
}

int
test_func() { 1; }

int
main() {
  Dl_info dli;
  int rc = dladdr((void *)test_func, &dli);
  printf("rc = %d\n", rc);
  if (rc) {
    printf("dli.dli_fname = %s\n", dli.dli_fname);
  }
}
```

**Update 30-Apr-2012:**
When I originally posted this question, I was also seeing loadquery(L_GETINFO) cause a segmentation violation when called from a 64-bit program. I can't live without 64-bit so this was a showstopper for me.  This now looks like it's a problem with the installation of the compiler; other AIX machines can compile and run the code in 64-bit mode.

The stack back-trace looked like this:

```
.() at 0xf458
usl_getinfo_user(??, ??, ??, ??) at 0x9fffffff00096b8
uloadquery(??, ??, ??, ??, ??, ??, ??) at 0x9fffffff0009b40
loadquery(0x200000002, 0x1000b3f0, 0xa0000000a000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0) at 0x900000000043874
dladdr(s = 0x0000000110000900, i = 0x0ffffffffffffa00), line 18 in "dladdr.c"
main(), line 11 in "test_dladdr.c"
```

Comment: note the relatively small number of followers each of your tags has (roll-over with mouse to see). As this is c code, you'll get a lot more eye-balls on your problem if you include a tag for 'c' (don't know if it called 'c' or 'c-lang' or ?? Good luck.

Comment: @shellter, yes you're right and I think it's 'c'.  I woke up this morning thinking exactly this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you need to read more about Pointer Glue on AIX and PowerPC, https://stackoverflow.com/a/1343437/89101 .  If you change to:

```
int rc = dladdr((void*)*((ulong*)&test_func), &dli);
```

that will get the *actual* address of `test_func` and you'll get the expected output of finding it in the main program.

I'm not sure why you get a crash with `loadquery` for 64-bit.  It works on my machine.  One thing that looks fishy is

```
loadquery(0x200000002, 0x1000b3f0, 0xa0000000a000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0) at 0x900000000043874
```

the `0xa0000000a000` looks to be too large, `40960` in hex should just be `0x00000000a000`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, although in terms of getting the address of test_func, I think you've got an extra ampersand in there that shouldn't be.  Once I removed that, your suggestion above worked.